# SQL: Select and Inner Join three tables in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, where-clause

I am trying to `JOIN` the result of the first `SELECT` clause, between the first 2 tables (`t1` and `t2`), with the third table (`t3`):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.PropertyCode, t3.TBMonth
 FROM  Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 , Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
 WHERE   t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid 
   OR t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid
 INNER JOIN Test.dbo.DailyTrialBalanceExtract T3 ON t1.AccCode = t3.AcctCode
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because of the three part naming for tables (and dbo), I removed the Oracle tag.

Comment: @VitorTyburski can you please help me with the right one?

Comment: @user3586244 GordonLinoff answer is already straight fowardly correct, but I added some info at mine that you might like ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax for your query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.PropertyCode, t3.TBMonth
FROM Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 JOIN
     Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
     ON t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid OR t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid INNER JOIN
     Test.dbo.DailyTrialBalanceExtract T3
     ON t1.AccCode = t3.AcctCode;
```

The `where` clause goes after the `from` clause.  But you don't need a `where` clause, just put the condition in the `on` clause, where it should go for an explicit join.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax might be clearer:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  t2.PropertyCode, 
  t3.TBMonth
FROM 
  Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 
    JOIN
  Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
    ON
  ( t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid 
      OR 
    t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid 
  )
    INNER JOIN
  Test.dbo.DailyTrialBalanceExtract T3
    ON 
  t1.AccCode = t3.AcctCode
;
```

Comment: It is the same answer already given 2 times. Please go for edits or comments.

Comment: @VitorTyburski I started answering before you posted, but, had to step away from my laptop.  I guess by the time that I got back, finished, and submitted, you beat me to it.  Respectfully, I also think that although the answers might be the same, my formatting, may help some newbies understand and "see" the solution better.  It seems that at least 4 other users agree.  Please reconsider your downvote... thx.

Answer (score 0):

Join are part of the projection, not selection (SQL databases make use of some [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)). Even if it happens to be executable in some DB (which I don´t think it is) you should avoid it.

You should use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS (which are knows as semi joins) instead.

The query below is a "transliteration" of your query. If it does not return what you want let me know.

```
SELECT  t1.*,
        t2.PropertyCode, 
        t3.TBMonth
FROM    Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1      
JOIN    Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
ON      (t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid OR t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid)
JOIN    Test.dbo.DailyTrialBalanceExtract T3 
ON      t1.AccCode = t3.AcctCode
```

If you happen to not need the "t3.TBMonth" field

```
SELECT  t1.*,
        t2.PropertyCode
FROM    Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1
JOIN    Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
ON      (t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid OR t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid)
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Test.dbo.DailyTrialBalanceExtract T3 WHERE t1.AccCode = t3.AcctCode)
```

TIPS and NOTES:

- At least in SQL Server there is no diff between "INNER JOIN" and "JOIN", so pick one and stay with it;
- Using "... FROM table1 t1, table t2" is the same as CROSS JOIN;
- Avoid having to do JOIN conditions with OR (you do a JOIN [aka INNER JOIN] with your "... FROM table1 t1, table t2" plus "t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid OR t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid") they slow down the query a lot;